# Unable to insert data into database with php

Tags: php, database, insert

I have a problem posting data in my database with a form. Very basic stuff I'm sure but Im quite stuck :/

I am able to get stuff out of my database using the select from database routine. So I know that the connection with the databse is probably not the problem.

This is my 'upload.php':

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="action.php" method="post">

        <fieldset class="first">
             Name: 
        <input type="text" name="author" />
        Heading:
          <input type="text" name="heading" />

        Text:
        <textarea type="text" name="thecontent"> </textarea>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
        <input type="submit"/> 
            </fieldset>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

And this is my 'action.php':

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Send!</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','name','pasword')
or die ("Unable to connect"); 

$mydb = mysql_select_db('the_database',$link)
or die ("No database found"); 

$author = $_POST['author']; 
$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$thecontent = $_POST['thecontent'];

$mysql_query="INSERT INTO articles ('heading', 'author', 'content')
 VALUES ('$heading','$author','$thecontent')" or die(mysql_error());   

echo "This was send: $author $heading $thecontent <br> ";


 mysql_close()

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

All help would be much appreciated!!

Cheers,
Ziggy

Thanks for all the help guys! I'm trying to use mysqli to insert the data however it's not yet working this is my new code in action.php:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Send!</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = '**';
$DB_PASS = '***';
$DB_NAME = '***';
@ $db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'Error.';
exit();
}

$author = $_POST['author']; 
$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$thecontent = $_POST['thecontent'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO articles ('heading', 'author', 'content')
 VALUES ('$heading','$author','$thecontent')';   

$result = $db->query($query);
    if ($result) {
    echo $db->affected_rows."This was added.";
    } 
    else {
    echo "somethings gone very wrong.";
    }

$db->close();




?> 

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong guys?
Help is much appreciated!

Cheers,
Ziggy

Comment: `mysql_*` methods are deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead (_prepared statements_)

Comment: Is mysql_error printing anything? What do you get if you echo out `$mysql_query` and run it directly in the database?

Comment: Do you have 'INSERT' permissions on the table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$mysql_query="INSERT INTO articles    ('heading', 'author', 'content')
 VALUES ('$heading','$author','$thecontent')";
mysql_query($mysql_query);
//required to run the query..

And mysql_close(); // missing :p
```

Comment: This is **deprecated** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456431/why-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You build the **INSERT** string, but you never call a method to realy **INSERT** the DB with it.

Moreover, old `mysql_*` methods are deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli` API instead, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

See also stackoverflow post about this : [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Some `PDO` prepared statements examples with `PDO` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php